# Could we prove all statements in arithmetic by repeated Gödelizations?

Tags: logic

I heard that, in a sense, any true proposition in arithmetic (a.k.a. statements about Turing Machines, Diophantine Equations, ...) can in principle be proved by repeated "Gödelizations" of the standard axioms of Arithmetic. We can start with a system F, then adjoin G(F) to F as an axiom to get F', and then adjoin G(F') to get F'', and so on.. Then we can see how to construct a finite system F*ω* by adjoining the infinite list of Gödel sentences to our original system F. This F*ω* will, in its turn, have a Gödel sentence G(F*ω*) that we could adjoin to F*ω* and so on until we reach higher and higher ordinals. Of course, knowing how to adjoin the infinite lists of axioms as finite lists will be incredibly difficult the further we go on with this procedure (and there is no reason to believe humans can go very far), yet it does seem that this procedure could at least *in principle* prove any statement in arithmetic.

But I also heard that some proofs of propositions in arithmetic make use of set-theoretic assumptions (e.g., a proposition that codes the consistency of a set-theoretical system), and that there is no known way to prove them only using the axioms of arithmetic. So doesn't this contradict the fact (discussed in previous paragraph) that all propositions in arithmetic could be proved (in principle) with repeated Gödelizations of the axioms of standard arithmetic without resort to set theory?

Would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: But if we add the infinite list of new axioms the resulting system is not finite.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I read that it is indeed the case that you could adjoin an infinite list of axioms as a single axiom (or a finite list of axioms), as long as the stage reached in this procedure is in the computable ordinals. (Penrose 1994, himself referring to Feferman 1988). Or do you mean that adding an axiom that systematizes an infinite list of axioms to the system would make it a set-theoretical one?

Comment: A crucial condition for Goedel's first incompleteness theorem  to appply is also that the theory has a recursively enumerable set of axioms. This is not the case , if we pack all true statements into it.

Comment: $Π_1$  jjjjjjjjjjjjj